# How can I import a tables into Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had 5 tables with a values which is exported from other system. Now, I want to import that 5 tables into my database. Is it any possibles to import ?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Import what into SQL server. "Tables" is not a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by the following step...

**Option 1: From Import and Export Data**

Click Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Import and Export Data option and follow steps in that wizard.

Which has the option to import and export data (see the below image for your ref.)

[image]

**Option 2: Tasks -> Import/Export Data**

or Connect your database in SQL Server 2008 R2 and right click on the database you desire and select `Tasks` and select option you want to do. (refer below image)

[image]

Refer: [Start the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Try with the following instructions:**

Right click on the Database Name>Task>Import data...>Next>Select Data Source and follow the next instructions.

For details->https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx